# How to run ant file in JetBrains WebStorm IDE?

Tags: ide, frontend, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, web-frontend

I want to migrate from Eclipse to WebStorm for front end programming. I have done a setup for WebStorm but I couldn't find the way to do:

1. Ant view - I couldn't find Ant view to run Ant files
2. File synchronizer - to synchronize the code from Eclipse editor to actual working domain folder, I used to use file synchronizer. For WebStorm - I have found remote file synchronizer plugin but either I am not able to use it or it is meant for something else.

Any help on these would be highly appreciated!!

Also, I used to work on multiple projects simultaneously. Is there any way in WebStorm to use multiple projects in same view (without opening different windows)? If it is not feasible to do these things in WebStorm please guide me to choose good IDE for frontend programming.

Comment: *"If it is not feasible to do these things in WebStorm please guide me to choose good IDE for frontend programming."* This site does not like such questions (comparison; what is better etc) as it's very subjective (somebody may like one tool/approach; another person may just hate it because he has different habits/different requirements).

Comment: 1) There is no Ant support in WebStorm -- only in IntelliJ IDEA -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16096. I do not know what you are using it .. but in front end these days tools like Gulp/Grunt/npm/webpack etc are widely used for your building/packing needs.

Comment: 2) *"File synchronizer"* I have not used Eclipse so have no clue what this tool/module does there. If you need to move your project files to another location -- it can be done with standard Deployment functionality (Remote Hosts Access plugin; installed and active by default).

Comment: 3) Nope -- only one project per window (frame). What you can do here .. is to attach any other folder as [Additional Content Root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/configuring-content-roots.html?search=content%20root) -- such folder will be listed as another node in Project View .. but will use settings from this project.

Comment: 4) In general I suggest to check out https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials  -- it's for PhpStorm .. but non-PHP stuff will remain the same. In particular -- you can start here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Eclipse+PDT+and+Eclipse-based+IDEs . Also blogs (http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/ & http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) -- they have good articles there from time to time (What's new; particular feature in details; Webinar recordings etc)